# How can I store data in array using formula in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I am trying to store the data that are evaluated in this block of code using the formula field in crystal report,

```
if "TOP" in {materialDescription} or 
   "Top" in {materialDescription}
then 
   //Storing the data into a TOP array here.
else
   //Storing the data into a BOTTOM array here.
```

Somebody help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not continue solving my problem using storing to array. I  just grouped my top and bottom with formula using the conditional if-then-else in crystal report.